# (Scp - Permission Denied (Public Key)

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, scp

I am trying to use the linux command **Scp** to get a file of a server xx.xx.xxx.xx and onto my Desktop. Here is my syntax

```
scp admin@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/scraper/summary.csv /home/barns/Desktop
```

I am getting the error

```
'permission denied (publickey)'
```

Is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 scp admin@xx.xx.xxx.xx:~/scraper/summary.csv /home/barns/Desktop
```

I needed a **~** symbol before the directory name

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's correct. Run the command with `-vvv` option to find out at what stage does it break exactly. It may be either a local issue (like private key being world-readable), remote (like your public key not being found), or something during the exchange (like no common ciphers). The debug output should give you information you need.

Comment: Thanks Viraptor, so something along the lines of "scp -vvv .......... "

Comment: exactly, just add `-vvv` option to the command that's causing problems