# Copy files from local machine to remote server in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, copy, remote-server

I need to copy a zip file to remote server from local machine. Tried following command :

```
scp /path-of-folder-which-needs-to-be-added-in-remote-server /username@remotr:where-to-add
```

Got error as :

```
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

What is the proper command to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(Scp - Permission Denied (Public Key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717436/scp-permission-denied-public-key)

Answer (score 0):

Your command **is** using the right syntax, however there's obviously an authentication error. Ensure you're using the right key for the respective server; if it's not set, use the `-i` parameter to set it at runtime. The syntax is `-i <identity_file>`, so provide your private key in place.